# Magento - how can I set router for all stores?

Tags: magento, module, frontend, router

I have set a Router file that extends the Standard.php Router.
It works if I set the router like this, however I want to be able to set "all stores". Is this possible? or do I have to change the config everytime I add a store.
Here is what I have for my config.xml:

```
    <stores>
<mystore1>
    <web>
        <routers>                               
            <myextension>
                <area>frontend</area>
                <class>Mymodule_Myextension_Controller_Router</class>
            </myextension>
        </routers>
    </web>
</mystore1>
</stores>
<frontend>
<routers>
    <myextension>
        <use>myextension</use>
        <args>
            <module>Mymodule_Myextension</module>
            <frontName>myextension</frontName>
        </args>
    </myextension>
</routers>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <myextension>
            <file>myextension.xml</file>
        </myextension>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the store to 'admin' and it will apply to all stores.

```
<admin>
    <web>
        <routers>                               
            <myextension>
                <area>frontend</area>
                <class>Mymodule_Myextension_Controller_Router</class>
            </myextension>
        </routers>
    </web>
</admin>
```

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?